# Write a function that takes a string parameter and returns a new string with all the letters of the alphabet that are not in the argument string

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Write a function called *missing_letters* that takes a string parameter and returns a new string with all the letters of the alphabet that are not in the argument string. The letters in the returned string should be in alphabetical order.**

**It should also use the global variable *alphabet*. It should use this global variable directly, not through an argument or a local copy. It should loop over the letters in alphabet to determine which are missing from the input parameter. 
The function *missing_letters* should combine the list of missing letters into a string and return that string.**

**Write a loop over the strings in list *test_miss* and call *missing_letters* with each string. Print a line for each string listing the missing letters. For example, for the string "aaa", the output should be the following.**

> aaa is missing letters bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

***I tried my best to solve this. The program is working but not giving
 the desired output.***

```
test_miss = ["b","zzz"] 
def missing_letters(s):
    missingAlphabets = ""
    global alphabet
    for c in s:
        i=0
        while i < len(alphabet):
            if alphabet[i] not in c:
                missingAlphabets += alphabet[i]
            i += 1
    sortedmissingAlphabetslists = sorted(missingAlphabets)
    sortedmissingAlphabets = ''.join(sortedmissingAlphabetslists)
    return sortedmissingAlphabets

for i in test_miss:
    print('{} is missing letters {}'.format(i,missing_letters(i)))
```

> #### the program is giving appropriate output for any string with a single character, like - "b"
>
> that is: b is missing letters acdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
> ### But for a string with multiple characters, like: "zzz" the output is:
>
> zzz is missing letters aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooopppqqqrrrssstttuuuvvvwwwxxxyyy
>
> **But I want:**
>   zzz is missing letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping with the spirit of what you have already defined.  The issue is that you are testing each letter in the `missing_letters` function more than once.  So you just want to check if the character (from the alphabet) is in the string.  So take out the extra `for loop` which loops through the letters in the argument - like such

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'    
test_miss = ["b","zzz"] 
def missing_letters(s):
    missingAlphabets = ""
    global alphabet
    i = 0
    while i < len(alphabet):
        if alphabet[i] not in s:
            missingAlphabets += alphabet[i]
        i += 1
    sortedmissingAlphabetslists = sorted(missingAlphabets)
    sortedmissingAlphabets = ''.join(sortedmissingAlphabetslists)
    return sortedmissingAlphabets

for i in test_miss:
    print('{} is missing letters {}'.format(i,missing_letters(i)))

b is missing letters acdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
zzz is missing letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, MichaelD, I was so close and made this newbie mistake. have a great day, peace.

Answer (score 3):

The `set` type already handles most of the work for you.

```
import string

def missing_letters(s):
    return ''.join(sorted(set(string.lowercase) - set(s)))
```

If `x` and `y` are sets, then `x - y` is the set of items present in `x` but not in `y`. One you have the set of missing characters, you can sort them and re-join the sorted elements into a single string.

```
>>> set('abc') - set('a')
set(['c', 'b'])
>>> sorted(_)
['b', 'c']
>>> ''.join(_)
'bc'
```

Comment: I'm really confused about your answer, how can I implement in my program?

Comment: That *is* the program. All your loops and and conditionals are just an attempt at re-implementing what `set.__sub__` already does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't know about the set. I'll use it later. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_duplicates(t):
   t= histogram(t)
   for i in t:
     a=(t[i])
     if a > 1:
        return True
   else:
         return False

for i in test_dups:
   f = has_duplicates(i)
   if f == True:
      print(i +' '+ 'has duplicates')
   else:
      print(i +' '+ 'has no duplicates')
```